# Custom Server-side Model validation tag helpers not appearing through unobtrusiveJS in ViewComponent

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a custom validation attribute I made for a group of checkboxes that are located inside of a ViewComponent. Before I moved it into the ViewComponent the unobtrusive validation message worked perfectly through the asp-validation-for, but now the message is not appearing there.

At the same time I am collecting the server-side validation errors and passing them back to the View, and that is working as expected: So I am getting the error message I made through the custom attribute, it's just not showing the message in the .

Here is the code (I am simplifying it where I can, please let me know if you need more info. I apologize if I left something out.):

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Enrollment(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
        {
            return View("~/Enrollment.cshtml", enrollmentVM);
        }


public EnrollmentViewModel SetModelListItems(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
        {
            if (enrollmentVM.Preferences == null)
            {
                var preferencesList = preferences.GetAll().ToList();
                enrollmentVM.Preferences = preferences.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = x.PreferencesName,
                    Value = x.PreferenceseId.ToString()
                }).ToList();
    return enrollmentVM;
    }
```

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
        {
 
            enrollmentVM = SetModelListItems(enrollmentVM);
                return new ViewViewComponentResult()
            {
                ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<EnrollmentViewModel>(ViewData, enrollmentVM)
            };
```

Main View:

```
@model EnrollmentViewModel;

@{
    Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
}
<button type="submit" id="EnrollForm" form="EnrollForm">
<span>Save</span>
</button>
<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("EnrollClient", new { enrollmentVM = @Model });                              
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    @if (Model.HasErrors)
    {

        @foreach (string errorMessage in Model.SubmitErrors)
        {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                toastr["error"]("@errorMessage");
            </script>
        }
}
```

ViewComponent:

```
@model EnrollmentViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("EnrollClient", "Enrollment", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "EnrollForm" }))
{
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Preferences (select all that apply)</legend>
     @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Preferences.Count(); i++)
     {
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Selected">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Selected">@Model.Races[i].Text</label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Value" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Text" />
  </div>
}
  <span asp-validation-for="Preferences" class="text-danger"></span>
</fieldset>
```

POST Method:

```
public IActionResult EnrollClient(EnrollmentViewModel viewModel)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    viewModel = SetModelListItems(viewModel);
                    viewModel.HasErrors = true;
                    viewModel.SubmitErrors = ModelState.Values
                        .SelectMany(state => state.Errors)
                        .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage);
                    return View("~/Enrollment.cshtml", viewModel);
                }
                SaveForm();
            }

//....
        }
```

ViewModel w/ Attribute:

```
public class EnrollmentViewModel
    {
    
        [ListItemSelected(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one Preference option.")]
        public List<SelectListItem> Preferences { get; set; }
    }
    
public class ListItemSelectedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if ((value as List<SelectListItem>).Count(x => x.Selected) == 0)
                    return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }

            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

I feel like this is a lot of code but hopefully most of it was necessary to explain my issue... I pared it down a lot. The jquery, validation, and unobtrusive scripts are in the _Layout.cshtml. Thank you so much!

**EDIT**:

I put a breakpoint in the ViewComponent and in the Main View files, and in both, in the Locals tab, the ViewContext is showing the ModelState is invalid, and the ValidationMessageElement = "span"! I guess that's not what it's supposed to be?? I found a post recommending to add ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext(); at the top, but with or without it the FormContext items are the same.

Comment: to be sure, have you tried putting a breakpoint in the ViewComponent's view file to examine its `ModelState`? There should be validation errors in there, otherwise somehow the tag helper is not working for `asp-validation-for`. BTW, I'm a bit doubting that this `asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Selected"` would render the corresponding name of `Selected`. Could you inspect your webpage (using the browser's inspector tool) to see what the actual names generated for your inputs are? The `asp-validation-for` looks however right.

Comment: @KingKing I did not know to do that(thank you). I did that and the ModelState is invalid, and the ValidationMessageElement = "span"! I guess that's not what it's supposed to be??

I googled around and found a post recommending to add `ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();` at the top, but with or without it the FormContext items are the same in the Locals tab.

Comment: you can inspect the `ModelState` deep down to the list of errors for each `ModelStateEntry`, ModelState here is an `IReadOnlyDictionary<string,ModelStateEntry>`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code, but the submit button is not fired. Also, I didn't see the `Enroll` action while you have set it in the Html.BeginForm

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Enroll", "Enrollment", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "EnrollForm" }))
```

I made an example based on your codes, which seems work as you expected.

Main View (Enrollment.cshtml)

```
@model EnrollmentViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Enrollment</h1>

<div>
    @await Component.InvokeAsync("EnrollClient", new { enrollmentVM = @Model })
</div>
```

ViewComponent(Default.cshtml):

```
@model EnrollmentViewModel
@{ 
    var x = Model;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Enroll", "Enrollment", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "EnrollForm" }))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Preferences (select all that apply)</legend>
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Preferences.Count(); i++)
    {
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Selected">
            <label>@Model.Preferences[i].Text</label>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Value" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Preferences[i].Text" />
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit" id="EnrollForm" form="EnrollForm">
        <span>Save</span>
    </button>
    <span asp-validation-for="Preferences" class="text-danger"></span>
</fieldset>
}
```

EnrollClientViewComponent.cs

```
public class EnrollClientViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
    {
        enrollmentVM = SetModelListItems(enrollmentVM);
        return new ViewViewComponentResult()
        {
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<EnrollmentViewModel>(ViewData, enrollmentVM)
        };

    }

    public EnrollmentViewModel SetModelListItems(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
    {
        enrollmentVM.Preferences = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "A", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "B", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "C", Value = "3"},
        };
        return enrollmentVM;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class EnrollmentController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Enrollment(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
    {
        return View("Enrollment", enrollmentVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Enroll(EnrollmentViewModel enrollmentVM)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Enrollment", enrollmentVM);
        }
        else
        {
            //SaveForm
            return View("Enrollment", enrollmentVM);
        }
    }
}
```

The project structure:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi! I fixed the error in my question. I think the central difference is that because I'm using a custom attribute in the VM, it's server-side validation only, and somehow the validation message is not making it back, though the ModelState is. (I updated my question with some more info). Thank you so much!